# ODI - Groovy scripts that set the Begin Mapping Comand & End Mapping Command with PL/SQL code

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

Using Groovy how could I change the Physical layer settings in all ODI maps, including PL / SQL code in Begin Mapping Command & End Mapping Command and sets the Technology for Begin Mapping Command/Location for Begin Mapping Command & Technology for End Mapping Command/Location for End Mapping Command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [IMappingFinder interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/index.html) lets you retrieve a collection of mappings (by project for instance).
For each element in the collection you can then use [getPhysicalDesign method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/Mapping.html#getPhysicalDesign-int-) to retrieve the physical design(s) of the mapping. From there, you can use the following methods to set the code, the technology and the logical schema :

- [setBeginCmd](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html#setBeginCmd-java.lang.String-)
- [setBeginCmdLogicalSchema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html#setBeginCmdLogicalSchema-oracle.odi.domain.adapter.topology.ILogicalSchema-)
- [setBeginCmdTechnology](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html#setBeginCmdTechnology-oracle.odi.domain.adapter.topology.ITechnology-)
- [setEndCmd](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html#setEndCmd-java.lang.String-)
- [setEndCmdLogicalSchema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html#setEndCmdLogicalSchema-oracle.odi.domain.adapter.topology.ILogicalSchema-)
- [setEndCmdTechnology](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html#setEndCmdTechnology-oracle.odi.domain.adapter.topology.ITechnology-)

However, if you need to add some code at the beginning and end of every mapping, it might be a good candidate for a custom Knowledge Module instead. You could duplicate your IKM, add a step at the beginning and one at the end and make sure you use the new KM. That's what KM are used for. Here is an example : https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/odi-12c-components-and-lkmsikms
The full documentation is here : https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odikd/developing-knowledge-modules-oracle-data-integrator.pdf